# POST one-to-many cascade relationship handling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an one-to-many relationship between class `Order` and `OrderLineItems`.

In class `Order` I have:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<OrderLineItem> orderLineItems = new ArrayList<OrderLineItem>();
```

In class `OrderLineItem` I have:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;
```

I am passing a **POST JSON to ORDER which has the body**:

```
{
    "orderName": "something",
    "orderAddress": "something",
    "companyName": "something",
    "companyAddress": "BLR",
    "billTo": "BLR",
    "shipTo": "BLR",
    "status": "NEW",
    "additionalCharges": 0,
    "requester": "USER",
    "orderLineItems": [
        {
            "productItemId": 1,
            "productName": "Product1",
            "sku": "SKU1",
            "packaging": "pack",
            "unitPrice": 100,
            "category": "1",
            "unitMeasure": 500,
            "tax": 5,
            "discount": 0,
            "quantity": 1,
            "comment": "NA",
            "lineItemTotalPrice": 105

        }
    ],
    "totalQuantity": 1,
    "totalPrice": 105,
    "totalLineItemPrice": 105,
    "orderLineItems": [
        {
            "productItemId": 1,
            "productName": "Product1",
            "sku": "SKU1",
            "packaging": "pack",
            "unitPrice": 100,
            "category": "1",
            "unitMeasure": 500,
            "tax": 5,
            "discount": 0,
            "quantity": 1,
            "comment": "NA",
            "lineItemTotalPrice": 105
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the following error, also I checked many similar posts on Stack Overflow and none of them solved my problem or, to phrase it better, I am starting with this thing.
So, here is the issue:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-14T17:13:08.694+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/api/v1/orders"
}
```

Detailed server error:

```
2018-06-14 22:43:08 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ORDER_ID' doesn't have a default value
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
```